# How can I install apps onto an iPad with iOS 5?

Tags: jailbreak, ios

I have a jailbroken iPad 1 (running iOS 5.1.1), and I would like to install some free apps on it (namely YouTube). Unfortunately the App Store won’t let me install most apps on such an old device.

Is there any way to work around this limitation and install an older version of those apps that would be compatible with my iPad and iOS 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an absolutely legal way to do what i want. I got my problem solved by Reddit user **mikkoko**, he said:

> Download desired app on iTunes, then when you go to App Stores purchased section on your device you'll be able to install last compatible version.

This works

Comment: This doesn't work for me on my iPad 2 running iOS 7.1.2.  Is this feature still supported?

Comment: @JAL it should work. I used this method recently. Did you get an app with iTunes before trying to download in from AppStore using iPad?

Comment: It was an app that was already in my purchase history.  The version number is the last compatible version of the app supported by iOS 7, but as soon as I push the cloud "download" button, the I get an alert that says "This application requires iOS 8.0 or later."